# Prevent single inline script from executing

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing own `.js` script for specific site but there is one terrible inline script that doesn't allow me to use `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. It's located in top of `<body>` and here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.localStorage.clear();
window.sessionStorage.clear();
</script>
```

As you can see, this awful script clears both storages every time page is reloaded. Is there any way to get rid of this script using own content script or chrome extension?

I have tried to use content script with `"run_at": "document_start"` as own chrome extension but it fails with `Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null'.
Here is my script's code:

```
var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
script.removeChild(script);
```

Comment: why can't you modify the generated page?

Comment: Because inline scripts are executed by browser as soon as browser reads closing `</script>` tag. So storages are both empty already when page is generated.

Comment: i mean why can't you modify the thing that is putting that script on there in the first place?

Comment: Because it's not my own site. Let's say it's online game, and I am making own bot. I have no access to php file that is generating page for me. I am just end user.

Comment: Lets look again at how you're trying to go about it. `script.removeChild(script)` - now replace the word `script` with the word `parent`. Yes, oh-dear indeed. What you probably intended to do was: `script.parentNode.removeChild(script);`

Comment: I have tried both `script.removeChild(script);` and `script.removeChild(parent);` but everytime I get the same error: `Cannot read property removeChild of undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get a script tag to run BEFORE that script then simply redefine those functions to do nothing.

```
window.localStorage.clear = function() {};
window.sessionStorage.clear = function() {};
```

Comment: The problem is exactly that I can't do it. When I use `@run-at document_start` parameter in manifest file of my Chrome extension, it executes my script too early, because there is no elements in the document. But when document is loaded it's too late.

Comment: This has nothing to do with elements in the document. Window always exists whether or not the document is yet loaded. Why don't you put the code in and see?

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I got what did you mean. It working just as needed.